# Why event listener doesnt work with class

Tags: javascript, html, events

I want to add an event listener to my input class to do some validation.

So here is my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" class="inputs form-control" id="input" tabindex="9" maxlength="2">


<script>

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("inputs");

input.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  let regEx = /^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/;
  let isHex = regEx.test(event.target.value.toString());
  if(!isHex) {
    elements.value = elements.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

So if I do that with id, the code works perfectly but it doesn't work with the class. SO do you know why?

Comment: Reading [the documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) is always useful.

Answer (score 1):

[`getElementsByClassName`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns an [HTMLCollection](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLCollection). You have to add the event listener to the first item in it.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" class="inputs form-control" id="input" tabindex="9" maxlength="2">


<script>

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("inputs")[0];

elements.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  let regEx = /^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/;
  let isHex = regEx.test(event.target.value.toString());
  if(!isHex) {
    elements.value = elements.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
})
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

If you want to add the event listener to each item, loop through the HTMLCollection:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<input type="text" class="inputs form-control" id="input" tabindex="9" maxlength="2">


<script>

var elements = [...document.getElementsByClassName("inputs")];

elements.forEach(e => e.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  let regEx = /^[0-9a-fA-F]+$/;
  let isHex = regEx.test(event.target.value.toString());
  if(!isHex) {
    elements.value = elements.value.slice(0, -1);
  }
}))
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `getElementsByClassName returns an HTMLCollection` - In that case, you are supposed to add the listener to all the elements having a specified class.